# How to open a file to save output in JavaScript using spidermonkey engine?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I wanted to export output of a JS programme [in spidermonkey JS engine] to a file, and the only way I was able to do it was using `js myfile.js >> output.txt` Is there any other way to write output to a file?